# Is there a way to find overlaps in time periods in two dataframes on Python and return the max and min timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two Pandas dataframes of events, with start and end times for time periods:

**DF1**

```
Group        amin             amax
1   2023-07-03 10:45:00 2023-07-03 16:00:00
2   2023-07-04 11:00:00 2023-07-04 11:00:00
3   2023-07-04 11:30:00 2023-07-04 18:15:00
```

**DF2**

```
Group        amin             amax  
1   2023-07-03 13:30:00 2023-07-03 13:30:00
2   2023-07-03 14:30:00 2023-07-03 15:30:00
3   2023-07-03 16:30:00 2023-07-03 16:30:00
4   2023-07-03 17:00:00 2023-07-03 17:00:00
5   2023-07-04 15:45:00 2023-07-04 16:30:00
```

Ideally, I'd like to iterate through the two dataframes to create a new dataframe that would find the overlap between them, and give the min and max of the overall overlap:

```
Group        amin             amax  
1   2023-07-03 10:45:00 2023-07-03 17:00:00
2   2023-07-04 11:30:00 2023-07-03 18:15:00
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: How is `2023-07-04 11:00:00` handled?

Comment: and `2023-07-03 17:00:00`?

Comment: If they fall in within the timerange of a period in the other dataframe, they'd be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dataframes you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "amin": ["2023-07-03 10:45:00", "2023-07-04 11:00:00", "2023-07-04 11:30:00"],
        "amax": ["2023-07-03 16:00:00", "2023-07-04 11:00:00", "2023-07-04 18:15:00"],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "amin": [
            "2023-07-03 13:30:00",
            "2023-07-03 14:30:00",
            "2023-07-03 16:30:00",
            "2023-07-03 17:00:00",
            "2023-07-04 15:45:00",
        ],
        "amax": [
            "2023-07-03 13:30:00",
            "2023-07-03 15:30:00",
            "2023-07-03 16:30:00",
            "2023-07-03 17:00:00",
            "2023-07-04 16:30:00",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
# Merge and use proper dtypes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(["amin", "amax"], ignore_index=True)
for col in ("amin", "amax"):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

# Remove rows with no intersections
df = df[
    ~(
        (df["amin"] >= df["amax"].shift(1))
        & (df["amax"] <= df["amin"].shift(-1).fillna(df["amax"].max()))
    )
]

# Remove rows contained within others
df = df[
    ~(
        ((df["amin"] >= df["amin"].shift(-1)) & (df["amax"] <= df["amax"].shift(-1)))
        | ((df["amin"] >= df["amin"].shift(1)) & (df["amax"] <= df["amax"].shift(1)))
    )
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

                 amin                amax
0 2023-07-03 10:45:00 2023-07-03 16:00:00
1 2023-07-04 11:30:00 2023-07-04 18:15:00
```